# Python Tkinter Radiobutton makes me crazy

Tags: python, class, tkinter, radio-button

I am learning Tkinter. I want to create a window that will have some`Radiobuttons and a button. When the button is clicked will print on terminal the selection from the Radiobuttons. I have all this code in classes. The problem is that when I click the button it prints empty space. You can see that if you press many times the button. If I take the code and I put it on a new python file it works fine. I really do not know what is the problem and how to fix it. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

The code that creates the problem the Radiobuttons in classes with other windows.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


class Window:
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Label(master, text="Logo").grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2)

        ttk.Button(master, text="Login", command=self.login).grid(row=0, column=1)

        ttk.Button(master, text="Register", command=self.register).grid(row=1, column=1)

    def login(self):
        root = Tk()
        login_window = Login(root)
        root.mainloop()

    def register(self):
        root = Tk()
        register_window = Register(root)
        root.mainloop()


class Login:
    def __init__(self, master):
        r = StringVar()

        ttk.Radiobutton(master, value="1", variable=r, text="1").grid(row=0, column=0)
        ttk.Radiobutton(master, value="2", variable=r, text="2").grid(row=1, column=0)
        ttk.Radiobutton(master, value="3", variable=r, text="3").grid(row=2, column=0)
        ttk.Radiobutton(master, value="4", variable=r, text="4").grid(row=3, column=0)

        ttk.Button(master, text="Select", command=lambda: self.button_select(r.get())).grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=4)

    def button_select(self, selection):
        print(selection)


class Register:
    def __init__(self, master):
        pass


def main():
    root = Tk()
    main_window = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code same code with the Radiobuttons without the rest of the windows and classes that works fine.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def button_select(selection):
    print(selection)


master = Tk()


r = StringVar()

ttk.Radiobutton(master, value="1", variable=r, text="1").grid(row=0, column=0)
ttk.Radiobutton(master, value="2", variable=r, text="2").grid(row=1, column=0)
ttk.Radiobutton(master, value="3", variable=r, text="3").grid(row=2, column=0)
ttk.Radiobutton(master, value="4", variable=r, text="4").grid(row=3, column=0)

ttk.Button(master, text="Select", command=lambda: button_select(r.get())).grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=4)

master.mainloop()
```

I tried taking the code out of the classes. It works just fine. I cannot find a reason why not working in the classes.

Comment: It is because you have multiple instances of `Tk()`.

Comment: Each Tk() opens a new window. How can it be done differently? Everything else works only the Radiobuttons don't.

Comment: It is because the `StringVar` is created in the first instance of `Tk()` but those radiobuttons are created in another instance.  Try `r = StringVar(master)`.

Comment: Or use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()` for windows other than the main window.